# want to convert OCR PDF to computer font

Tags: pdf, conversion, editing, font-rendering, ocr

my pdf text is too blurry. so i want to convert it to computer font from scanned image.i already tried increassing quality by adobe/edit/preferences/page display.

[image: ht]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the original image of the text is "in front" of the actual digital text of the PDF.

| Figure 1: How layers are stacked in a PDF |
| --- |
| [image: image layer in front of the text layer] |

PDF is composed of overlapping visible and invisible layers. OCR attempts to use algorithms to identify text placement and size, then place text objects under the original images of the pages.

See these blog entries: [blogs.acrobat.com](https://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/?s=ocr%20and%20image%20layer)

Also, please see question by @tel [here](https://superuser.com/questions/178123/how-to-replaces-images-of-text-in-pdfs-with-formatted-text-using-ocr) for additional discussion: 
[How to replaces images of text in PDFs with formatted text using OCR](https://superuser.com/questions/178123/how-to-replaces-images-of-text-in-pdfs-with-formatted-text-using-ocr)

Without a professional subscription, I would use Adobe Acrobat DC to output as [XML](https://superuser.com/questions/278260/how-do-i-see-the-xml-of-my-docx-document) or DOCX, [go into the XML](https://superuser.com/questions/278260/how-do-i-see-the-xml-of-my-docx-document) and remove the images (e.g., using a regular expression), then try to apply text correction to the resulting document.

| Figure 2: ABBYY FineReader 15 Option |
| --- |
| [image: ABBYY FineReader 15 documentation showing save options with "Formatted Text" highlighted] |

By the way, [ABBYY FineReader](https://help.abbyy.com/en-us/finereader/15/user_guide/stepsave) has an option to save your OCR results as pure text — not invisible text under an image of the text. The software isn't cheap, but the investment can make sense if you're often doing OCR.